# simple numeric validation in jquery for input

Tags: jquery, validation, numeric

can anyone help me for simple jquery numeric validation?

```
<input type="text" name="yourphone" id="yourphone" required style="border-radius:6px; border:1px solid #ccc; width:300px; height:25px;" />
<input type="submit" value="Send Inquiry" class="button" id="mySubmitButton" />
```

Comment: Numeric validation for what? Checking integers? Floats? Max/Min? I assume phone number from reading the code.. Tell us what you're trying do to, and what you've already tried to achieve it.

Comment: Sure, change the input type from `text` to `number` !

Comment: To the right, to the right - all your answers in the list to the right

Answer (score 7):

You can change your input type to number like `<input type="number"...` (although not all browsers support HTML5 input types).

**Or** you can use this:

```
$('#myform').on('submit', function(){
    var value = $('#yourphone').val()
    return $.isNumeric(value);
});
```

but phone numbers can be complex, not just numbers.

**In case** the user uses `+` `(` `)` `-` `.` `,` you can use this:
(**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JsqNR/)**)

```
$('#myform').on('submit', function(){
    var value = $('#yourphone').val()
    var regex = new RegExp(/^\+?[0-9(),.-]+$/);
    if(value.match(regex)) {return true;}
    return false;
});
```

Comment: or just `return $.isNumeric(value);`

Comment: Yes, did that and added a regex alternative too.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myform').on('submit', function(){

    var value = $('#yourphone').val()
    var regex = new RegExp(/^\+?[0-9(),.-]+$/);
    if(value.match(regex)) {return true;}
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var specialKeys = new Array();
    specialKeys.push(8); //Backspace
    $(function () {
        $(".numeric").bind("keypress", function (e) {
            var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode
            var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || specialKeys.indexOf(keyCode) != -1);
            $(".error").css("display", ret ? "none" : "inline");
            return ret;
        });
        $(".numeric").bind("paste", function (e) {
            return false;
        });
        $(".numeric").bind("drop", function (e) {
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```